# getting an error when trying to make a function to return a list in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm getting a compile-time error when trying to return the var projectList witch is a list from a given struct that I created. The compile error I'm getting is: '[teamProjects]' is not convertible to void.  but i believe that the functioin is of type [teamProjects]

Here is my code:

```
func makeHTTPRequest(url: String, usr: String, pw: String) -> [teamProjects]{

        var projectList: [teamProjects] = []

        for index in 0...(count-1) {

            let id = jsonOBJ[index]["id"].string as String! ?? ""
            let name: String = jsonOBJ[index]["name"].string as String! ?? ""
            let desc: String = jsonOBJ[index]["description"].string as String! ?? ""
            let url: String = jsonOBJ[index]["url"].string as String! ?? ""
            let state: String = jsonOBJ[index]["state"].string as String! ?? ""
            let revision: Int = jsonOBJ[index]["revision"].int as Int! ?? 0

            let teamProject: teamProjects = teamProjects(id: id, name: name,
            description: desc, url: url, state: state, revision: revision)

                projectList.append(teamProject);
            }

            println(projectList)
            return projectList
    }
```

I’m I declaring it wrong?

Comment: What if you change your array declaration to var projectList = [teamProjects]()

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not doing something wrong and in my Xcode 7 beta 6 the following piece of code works without a compelling error. in general the way you have declared the function is correct.